# I am Getting invalid file operation error though file is present in my local system

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace directory MYCSV as 'E:\sqlloader\';

grant read, write on directory MYCSV to public;

declare
  F UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  V_LINE VARCHAR2 (1000);
  V_id NUMBER(4);
  V_NAME VARCHAR2(10);
  V_risk VARCHAR2(10);
   
BEGIN
  F := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('MYCSV', 'testfile.csv', 'R');
  IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(F) THEN
    LOOP
      BEGIN
        UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(F, V_LINE, 1000);
        IF V_LINE IS NULL THEN
          EXIT;
        END IF;
        V_id := REGEXP_SUBSTR(V_LINE, '[^,]+', 1, 1);
        V_NAME := REGEXP_SUBSTR(V_LINE, '[^,]+', 1, 2);
        V_risk := REGEXP_SUBSTR(V_LINE, '[^,]+', 1, 3);
        INSERT INTO loader_tab VALUES(V_id, V_NAME, V_risk);
        COMMIT;
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          EXIT;
      END;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F);
END;
/
```

CSV file content wherein I need to start loading from 1,a,aa and need to skip first 4 lines:

```
portal,,
ex portal,,
,,
i_id,i_name,risk
1,a,aa
2,b,bb
3,c,cc
4,d,dd
5,e,ee
6,f,ff
7,g,gg
8,h,hh
9,i,ii
10,j,jj
```

I want to load the data from excel but I am getting an invalid file operation error. Will someone help with this? Not able to load the data from an excel file. I am Getting invalid file operation error though file is present in my local system.

Comment: The [tag:oracle-sqldeveloper] and [tag:plsqldeveloper] tags are for questions about using those desktop tools specifically. Please don't use them for general SQL or PL/SQL questions where the tool doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

> though file is present in my local system

It won't work unless *your local system* (I presume you mean your own PC) also runs the database into which you're trying to load data. Oracle directory (probably in 99% of all cases) resides **on the database server**.

---

> I want to load the data from excel

It won't work either, if that's really an Excel file. Code you posted suggests that it is a comma-separated values file (textual, that is), and yes - it should be such a file, not XLSX.